# Docker multi-stage with AWS CLI

Tags: docker, aws-cli, docker-multi-stage-build

I am setting up a multistage build in Docker where I need to pull some data from a remote image. In that remote image, I see they installed the AWS CLI using the following set of commands in order to get it into an Alpine-based image:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add python3 && \
    pip3 install awscli && \
    aws --version
```

The copy say it's just fine

```
COPY --from=remote_setup /usr/bin/terraform /usr/bin/terraform
COPY --from=remove_setup /usr/bin/aws /usr/bin/aws
```

Terraform here runs peachy, but AWS does not.  The output looks like this:

```
/ # terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.2

/ # ls -lh /usr/bin | grep aws
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         817 Jun 19 19:51 aws
/ # aws --version
/bin/sh: aws: not found
```

If I add python3, I then get this error:

```
/ # aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli'
```

Is there a trick to copying over all the data from a command in that particular layer to my new one or for simplicity's sake should I just install Python and the AWS CLI myself in my image?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you install the python and awscli instead? Installing will make sure that it downloads all the dependencies and set up the required configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` is the standard Python package manager.  In addition to installing a wrapper script in `/usr/bin` (or the current environment's `bin` directory) it also installs a fair bit of library code under a `.../lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/...` tree.  Also, packages are allowed to depend on other packages, so it's not going to just be a single directory in the `site-packages` directory.

In short: you will need the Python interpreter and everything the `pip install` installs, so you should run that command yourself in your derived image.